Long cushion for lounge chair or sofa
I was doing some research and found this interesting lounge chair concept where the cushion connects the seat and backrest. 
I have been watching tutorials on making cushions in Blender mainly using the pressure tool in cloth.
But in this case, the cushion is longer, with 2 different angles and a crease in the middle. What would be the best way to achieve this result in Blender?
Thanks a lot
Valentin

Create this kind of mesh, assign these vertices to a vertex group that will be your cloth pin group:

Make it bloat with the Cloth physic, here the Pressure is set to 1 and I've cut the Gravity so that it doesn't fall, stop the animation when it is bloated enough:

To get the border seam, apply the Cloth modifier and extrude a face loop around the side:

Result with a Subdivision Surface modifier:

